# Change img src when clicked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some HTML code:

```
<div class="text-center img-big">
  <!-- IMAGE BIG  -->
  <img class="img-fluid img-big" src="" alt="">
</div>

<!-- IMAGE SMALL  -->
<a id="getImg" href="" ><img src="img/asus.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumbnail thumb-product img-fluid thumb-first" width="100"></a>

<a id="getImg" href="" ><img src="img/asus-thumb.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumbnail thumb-product img-fluid" width="100"></a>

<img src="img/asus.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumbnail thumb-product img-fluid" width="100">
```

and this is my some jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var imgSrc = $(".thumb-first").attr("src");
  $(".img-big").attr("src",imgSrc);

  $("#getImg img").on("click",function(){
    tes = $(this).attr("src");
    $(".img-big").attr("src",imgSrc);
  });
</script>
```

I want to change src image big when image small clicked, but my code doesn't work properly.

[image]

Comment: do you see any errors in console..? Btw, there are 2 elements with class `img-big`, so `$(".img-big")` might not return the one you want. Try being explicit like `$("img.img-big")` to get `img` element with class `img-big`

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: you have used `getImg` id twice...which is not valid...Also its not clear what you are doing...you have used three small images for `asus`...why???...better to edit your question

Comment: Do you want the source of the small image to be "transferred" to the big image after clicking?

Comment: no error in console, when i clicked small img, src of image big has changed, but back again as before

Comment: You should preventDefault action in A tag. Or remove A tags.

Comment: @Swellar  yeah like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is to change `id="getImg"` to `class="getImg"` because `id` attribute should always be unique.

Instead of getting the click event of the image, I used the click event of `<a>`, then located the `<img>` using `find()`.

I also added an `id` to the big image, because there are two instance of `.img-big`, which is an `<img>` and `<div>`, and `<div>` does not have a `src` attribute.

Lastly, I used `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the redirection when clicking a `<a>` tag

```js
$(".getImg").click(function(e) {
  var imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
  $("#bigImage").attr("src", imgSrc);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center img-big">
  <!-- IMAGE BIG  -->
  <img id="bigImage" class="img-fluid img-big" src="" alt="">
</div>

<!-- IMAGE SMALL  -->
<a class="getImg" href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="" class="img-thumbnail thumb-product img-fluid thumb-first" width="100"></a>

<a class="getImg" href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="" class="img-thumbnail thumb-product img-fluid" width="100"></a>
```

Comment: it's work, thanks bro

Answer (score 2):

First, you have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute.

Second, `tes` variable here is not defined.

```
tes = $(this).attr("src");
```

Third, try placing your javascript at the bottom of the html page or place your javascript code inside the ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give `getImg`, it can be done through `onclick` function. Try my code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center img-big">
  <!-- IMAGE BIG  -->
  <img class="img-fluid img-big" src="" alt="">
</div>

<!-- IMAGE SMALL  -->
<a href="javascript:;" ><img onclick="change_img(this)" src="Egg.png" alt="" class="img-thumbnail thumb-product img-fluid thumb-first" width="100"></a>

<a href="javascript:;" ><img onclick="change_img(this)" src="Fish.png" alt="" class="img-thumbnail thumb-product img-fluid" width="100"></a>
 


<script>
    function change_img(param){
        var src = $(param).prop('src');
        $('.img-big').prop('src',src);
    }
</script>
```